# Analyzing naming conventions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn

I just created a naming convention analyzer + code fix based on the Roslyn platform. The implemented naming conventions are the following:

[image]

If you're interested in seeing all the test scenarios that have been covered, you can take a look [here](https://github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics/blob/issue25/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics.Test/Tests/General/NamingConventionsAnalyzerTests.cs).

Some notes about the implementation:

- Analyzers and code fixes cannot share data between each other, which is a major pain. That's why I have to go find out which convention to use in my analyzer and do that again in my code fix. Though now that I think about it: maybe I can extract this common behaviour to a helper method. It's still double work but at least I won't have to write it double. Feel free to provide a proposal implementation.
- Verbatim identifiers (`@class`) and Unicode-littered identifiers (`cl\u0061ss`) are not applicable for a renaming.
- If the identifier contains special characters, I don't touch it either.
- I just realized I didn't account for members without explicit modifiers. You can ignore that aspect and pretend I don't do them.

You can view the PR related to this post [here](https://github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics/pull/80/files).

### Analyzer

```
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics;
using VSDiagnostics.Utilities;

namespace VSDiagnostics.Diagnostics.General.NamingConventions
{
    [DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
    public class NamingConventionsAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
    {
        public const string DiagnosticId = nameof(NamingConventionsAnalyzer);
        internal const string Title = "A member does not follow naming conventions.";
        internal const string Message = "The {0} {1} does not follow naming conventions. Should be {2}.";
        internal const string Category = "General";
        internal const DiagnosticSeverity Severity = DiagnosticSeverity.Warning;
        internal static DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, Message, Category, Severity, true);
        public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics => ImmutableArray.Create(Rule);

        public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
        {
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeSymbol,
                SyntaxKind.FieldDeclaration,
                SyntaxKind.PropertyDeclaration,
                SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration,
                SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration,
                SyntaxKind.InterfaceDeclaration,
                SyntaxKind.LocalDeclarationStatement,
                SyntaxKind.Parameter);
        }

        private void AnalyzeSymbol(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            var nodeAsField = context.Node as FieldDeclarationSyntax;
            if (nodeAsField != null)
            {
                if (nodeAsField.Declaration == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                foreach (var variable in nodeAsField.Declaration.Variables)
                {
                    SyntaxToken conventionedIdentifier;

                    if (nodeAsField.Modifiers.Any(x => new[] { "internal", "protected", "public" }.Contains(x.Text)))
                    {
                        conventionedIdentifier = variable.Identifier.WithConvention(NamingConvention.UpperCamelCase);
                    }
                    else if (nodeAsField.Modifiers.Any(x => x.Text == "private"))
                    {
                        conventionedIdentifier = variable.Identifier.WithConvention(NamingConvention.UnderscoreLowerCamelCase);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return; // Code is in incomplete state
                    }

                    if (conventionedIdentifier.Text != variable.Identifier.Text)
                    {
                        context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, variable.Identifier.GetLocation(), "field", variable.Identifier.Text, conventionedIdentifier.Text));
                    }
                }

                return;
            }

            var nodeAsProperty = context.Node as PropertyDeclarationSyntax;
            if (nodeAsProperty != null)
            {
                var conventionedIdentifier = nodeAsProperty.Identifier.WithConvention(NamingConvention.UpperCamelCase);
                if (conventionedIdentifier.Text != nodeAsProperty.Identifier.Text)
                {
                    context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, nodeAsProperty.Identifier.GetLocation(), "property", nodeAsProperty.Identifier.Text, conventionedIdentifier.Text));
                }
                return;
            }

            var nodeAsMethod = context.Node as MethodDeclarationSyntax;
            if (nodeAsMethod != null)
            {
                var conventionedIdentifier = nodeAsMethod.Identifier.WithConvention(NamingConvention.UpperCamelCase);
                if (conventionedIdentifier.Text != nodeAsMethod.Identifier.Text)
                {
                    context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, nodeAsMethod.Identifier.GetLocation(), "method", nodeAsMethod.Identifier.Text, conventionedIdentifier.Text));
                }
                return;
            }

            var nodeAsClass = context.Node as ClassDeclarationSyntax;
            if (nodeAsClass != null)
            {
                var conventionedIdentifier = nodeAsClass.Identifier.WithConvention(NamingConvention.UpperCamelCase);
                if (conventionedIdentifier.Text != nodeAsClass.Identifier.Text)
                {
                    context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, nodeAsClass.Identifier.GetLocation(), "class", nodeAsClass.Identifier.Text, conventionedIdentifier.Text));
                }
                return;
            }

            var nodeAsInterface = context.Node as InterfaceDeclarationSyntax;
            if (nodeAsInterface != null)
            {
                var conventionedIdentifier = nodeAsInterface.Identifier.WithConvention(NamingConvention.InterfacePrefixUpperCamelCase);
                if (conventionedIdentifier.Text != nodeAsInterface.Identifier.Text)
                {
                    context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, nodeAsInterface.Identifier.GetLocation(), "interface", nodeAsInterface.Identifier.Text, conventionedIdentifier.Text));
                }
                return;
            }

            var nodeAsLocal = context.Node as LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax;
            if (nodeAsLocal != null)
            {
                if (nodeAsLocal.Declaration == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                foreach (var variable in nodeAsLocal.Declaration.Variables)
                {
                    var conventionedIdentifier = variable.Identifier.WithConvention(NamingConvention.LowerCamelCase);
                    if (conventionedIdentifier.Text != variable.Identifier.Text)
                    {
                        context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, variable.Identifier.GetLocation(), "local", variable.Identifier.Text, conventionedIdentifier.Text));
                    }
                }

                return;
            }

            var nodeAsParameter = context.Node as ParameterSyntax;
            if (nodeAsParameter != null)
            {
                var conventionedIdentifier = nodeAsParameter.Identifier.WithConvention(NamingConvention.LowerCamelCase);
                if (conventionedIdentifier.Text != nodeAsParameter.Identifier.Text)
                {
                    context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, nodeAsParameter.Identifier.GetLocation(), "parameter", nodeAsParameter.Identifier.Text, conventionedIdentifier.Text));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Code Fix

```
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Composition;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeActions;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeFixes;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using VSDiagnostics.Utilities;

namespace VSDiagnostics.Diagnostics.General.NamingConventions
{
    [ExportCodeFixProvider("NamingConventions", LanguageNames.CSharp), Shared]
    public class NamingConventionsCodeFix : CodeFixProvider
    {
        public override ImmutableArray<string> FixableDiagnosticIds => ImmutableArray.Create(NamingConventionsAnalyzer.DiagnosticId);
        public override FixAllProvider GetFixAllProvider() => WellKnownFixAllProviders.BatchFixer;

        public override async Task RegisterCodeFixesAsync(CodeFixContext context)
        {
            var root = await context.Document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(context.CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var diagnostic = context.Diagnostics.First();
            var diagnosticSpan = diagnostic.Location.SourceSpan;

            var identifier = root.FindToken(diagnosticSpan.Start);
            context.RegisterCodeFix(CodeAction.Create("Rename", x => RenameAsync(context.Document, root, identifier)), diagnostic);
        }

        private Task<Solution> RenameAsync(Document document, SyntaxNode root, SyntaxToken identifier)
        {
            var identifierParent = identifier.Parent;
            var newIdentifier = default(SyntaxToken);

            do
            {
                var parentAsField = identifierParent as FieldDeclarationSyntax;
                if (parentAsField != null)
                {
                    if (parentAsField.Modifiers.Any(x => new[] { "internal", "protected", "public" }.Contains(x.Text)))
                    {
                        newIdentifier = identifier.WithConvention(NamingConvention.UpperCamelCase);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newIdentifier = identifier.WithConvention(NamingConvention.UnderscoreLowerCamelCase);
                    }
                    break;
                }

                if (identifierParent is PropertyDeclarationSyntax || identifierParent is MethodDeclarationSyntax || identifierParent is ClassDeclarationSyntax)
                {
                    newIdentifier = identifier.WithConvention(NamingConvention.UpperCamelCase);
                    break;
                }

                if (identifierParent is LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax || identifierParent is ParameterSyntax)
                {
                    newIdentifier = identifier.WithConvention(NamingConvention.LowerCamelCase);
                    break;
                }

                if (identifierParent is InterfaceDeclarationSyntax)
                {
                    newIdentifier = identifier.WithConvention(NamingConvention.InterfacePrefixUpperCamelCase);
                    break;
                }

                identifierParent = identifierParent.Parent;
            } while (identifierParent != null);

            var newParent = identifierParent.ReplaceToken(identifier, newIdentifier);
            var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(identifierParent, newParent);
            return Task.FromResult(document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot).Project.Solution);
        }
    }
}
```

### Extensions

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;

namespace VSDiagnostics.Utilities
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static SyntaxToken WithConvention(this SyntaxToken identifier, NamingConvention namingConvention)
        {
            // int @class = 5;
            if (identifier.IsVerbatimIdentifier())
            {
                return identifier;
            }

            // int cl\u0061ss = 5;
            if (identifier.Text.Contains("\\"))
            {
                return identifier;
            }

            var originalValue = identifier.ValueText;
            string newValue;

            switch (namingConvention)
            {
                case NamingConvention.LowerCamelCase:
                    newValue = GetLowerCamelCaseIdentifier(originalValue);
                    break;
                case NamingConvention.UpperCamelCase:
                    newValue = GetUpperCamelCaseIdentifier(originalValue);
                    break;
                case NamingConvention.UnderscoreLowerCamelCase:
                    newValue = GetUnderscoreLowerCamelCaseIdentifier(originalValue);
                    break;
                case NamingConvention.InterfacePrefixUpperCamelCase:
                    newValue = GetInterfacePrefixUpperCamelCaseIdentifier(originalValue);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException(nameof(namingConvention));
            }

            return SyntaxFactory.Identifier(identifier.LeadingTrivia, newValue, identifier.TrailingTrivia);
        }

        // lowerCamelCase
        private static string GetLowerCamelCaseIdentifier(string identifier)
        {
            if (ContainsSpecialCharacters(identifier))
            {
                return identifier;
            }

            var normalizedString = GetNormalizedString(identifier);

            if (normalizedString.Length >= 1)
            {
                return char.ToLower(normalizedString[0]) + normalizedString.Substring(1);
            }
            return identifier;
        }

        // UpperCamelCase
        private static string GetUpperCamelCaseIdentifier(string identifier)
        {
            if (ContainsSpecialCharacters(identifier))
            {
                return identifier;
            }

            var normalizedString = GetNormalizedString(identifier);

            if (normalizedString.Length == 0)
            {
                return identifier;
            }
            return char.ToUpper(normalizedString[0]) + normalizedString.Substring(1);
        }

        // _lowerCamelCase
        private static string GetUnderscoreLowerCamelCaseIdentifier(string identifier)
        {
            if (ContainsSpecialCharacters(identifier, '_'))
            {
                return identifier;
            }

            var normalizedString = GetNormalizedString(identifier);
            if (normalizedString.Length == 0)
            {
                return identifier;
            }

            if (normalizedString.Length == 1)
            {
                return "_" + char.ToLower(normalizedString[0]);
            }

            // _Var
            if (normalizedString[0] == '_' && char.IsUpper(normalizedString[1]))
            {
                return "_" + char.ToLower(normalizedString[1]) + normalizedString.Substring(2);
            }

            // Var
            if (char.IsUpper(normalizedString[0]))
            {
                return "_" + char.ToLower(normalizedString[0]) + normalizedString.Substring(1);
            }

            // var
            if (char.IsLower(normalizedString[0]))
            {
                return "_" + normalizedString;
            }

            return normalizedString;
        }

        // IInterface
        private static string GetInterfacePrefixUpperCamelCaseIdentifier(string identifier)
        {
            if (ContainsSpecialCharacters(identifier))
            {
                return identifier;
            }

            var normalizedString = GetNormalizedString(identifier);

            if (normalizedString.Length <= 1)
            {
                return identifier;
            }

            // iSomething
            if (normalizedString[0] == 'i' && char.IsUpper(normalizedString[1]))
            {
                return "I" + normalizedString.Substring(1);
            }

            // isomething
            if (char.IsLower(normalizedString[0]) && char.IsLower(normalizedString[1]))
            {
                return "I" + char.ToUpper(normalizedString[0]) + normalizedString.Substring(1);
            }

            // Isomething
            if (normalizedString[0] == 'I' && char.IsLower(normalizedString[1]))
            {
                return "I" + char.ToUpper(normalizedString[1]) + normalizedString.Substring(2);
            }

            return normalizedString;
        }

        private static string GetNormalizedString(string input)
        {
            return new string(input.ToCharArray().Where(x => char.IsLetter(x) || char.IsNumber(x)).ToArray());
        }

        private static bool ContainsSpecialCharacters(string input, params char[] allowedCharacters)
        {
            return !input.ToCharArray().All(x => char.IsLetter(x) || char.IsNumber(x) || allowedCharacters.Contains(x));
        }
    }
}
```

### NamingConvention

```
namespace VSDiagnostics.Utilities
{
    public enum NamingConvention
    {
        UpperCamelCase,
        LowerCamelCase,
        UnderscoreLowerCamelCase,
        InterfacePrefixUpperCamelCase
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> if (nodeAsField.Modifiers.Any(x => new[] { "internal", "protected", "public" }.Contains(x.Text)))
> {
>     // ...
> }
> else if (nodeAsField.Modifiers.Any(x => x.Text == "private"))
> {
>     // ...
> }
> ```

I find the following alternative a little easier to read, and less prone to typos:

```
var modifiers = nodeAsField.Modifiers;
if (modifiers.Any(SyntaxKind.InternalKeyword) ||
    modifiers.Any(SyntaxKind.ProtectedKeyword) ||
    modifiers.Any(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))
{
    // ...
}
else if (modifiers.Any(SyntaxKind.PrivateKeyword))
{
    // ...
}
```

It might also be more performant since we avoid string comparisons and array allocations in the lambda (though of course you should measure this yourself).

[Heap Allocations Viewer](https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/ReSharper.HeapView/) also warns that in the original code `nodeAsField.Modifiers` is boxed.

I noticed that structs are missing from both the naming conventions table and the code.

Answer (score 4):

You're accessing the `Identifier` more than often enough here to use a variable, in my humble opinion.

> ```
> var conventionedIdentifier = nodeAsMethod.Identifier.WithConvention(NamingConvention.UpperCamelCase);
>  if (conventionedIdentifier.Text != nodeAsMethod.Identifier.Text)
>  {
>      context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, nodeAsMethod.Identifier.GetLocation(), "method", nodeAsMethod.Identifier.Text, conventionedIdentifier.Text));
>  }
> ```

Doing so would dramatically reduce the horizontal scroll.

This logic gets repeated an awful lot too. It only differs in a few places. It should be possible to extract a method something like this.

```
private Diagnostic CheckNode(Node node, SyntaxKind kind)
{
    Diagnostic diagnostic = null;

    // some code to dynamically cast??

    if (node != null)
    {
        var conventionedIdentifier = node.Identifier.WithConvention(GetNamingConvention(kind));
        if (conventionedIdentifier.Text != node.Identifier.Text)
        {
            diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, node.Identifier.GetLocation(), GetFriendlySyntaxKindText(kind), node.Identifier.Text, conventionedIdentifier.Text);
        }
    }

    return diagnostic;
}
```

Untested and the types might not be right, but I'm sure you get the gist. There are also a couple of unimplemented methods in there. They'll let you abstract away the decisions you made for each different `SyntaxKind` into single methods in the source code.

The calling code will end up looking significantly different.

```
 diagnostic = CheckNode(context.Node, SyntaxKind.PropertyDeclaration);

 if (diagnostic != null) 
 {
     context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
     return;
 }

 diagnostic = CheckNode(context.Node, SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration);

 if (diagnostic != null) 
 {
     context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
     return;
 }
```

Which is going to turn into a second round of refactoring where you determine the kind dynamically *somehow*. (So don't know how though.)

Comment: I updated the code with 3 changes: implicit access modifiers for `private` fields are now accounted for, I drastically improved readability of the analyzer but couldn't get it as far as I wanted to due to Roslyn's inheritance structure and I removed some pointless code for fixing the naming of `_lowerCamelCase` types. All changes can be found in this commit: https://github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics/commit/1b4a796fb48def6a1239365731fb491f847cc74f?diff=split

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of unexpected results returned by the code fix provider:

- `GetInterfacePrefixUpperCamelCaseIdentifier("Foo") => Foo`, expected `IFoo`
- `GetLowerCamelCaseIdentifier("_foo") => _foo`, expected `foo`
- `GetUpperCamelCaseIdentifier("_foo") => _foo`, expected `Foo`
- `GetInterfacePrefixUpperCamelCaseIdentifier("_foo") => _foo`, expected `IFoo`

Comment: I think I've now covered these and a few more: https://github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics/commit/52beabe241bd8942cc8c1464092c3d464ecb93ab